# How can I use a ColorStateList within a ViewHolder for a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, user-interface, colors, formatting

I'm trying to use a ColorStateList to colorize the elements in my RecyclerView. Here's the xml for my ViewHolder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/view_colors"
>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8sp"
        android:id="@+id/entry_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8sp"
        android:id="@+id/entry_text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my view_colors.xml, which holds the Color State List:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"   
android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<item android:state_focused="true"   android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</selector>
```

When I used a ColorStateList in res/colors and applied it to a textColor tag, it worked fine. I tried the same with the background tag, and got this error. So I looked at other questions here and then tried to use an xml in res/drawable that defined drawables instead of colors (as seen above) but that didn't fix the issue.

EDIT: This works fine on my phone with API level 27, but the error shows up on my API level 23  phone.

Here's the full stack trace: 2019-04-12 13:47:39.419 22410-22410/com.example.realrecyclerview E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=31]
2019-04-12 13:47:39.419 22410-22410/com.example.realrecyclerview E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/app/com.example.realrecyclerview-1/oat/arm/base.odex". Will use given name.
2019-04-12 13:47:41.305 22410-22410/com.example.realrecyclerview E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=38]
2019-04-12 13:47:41.305 22410-22410/com.example.realrecyclerview E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/system/lib/hw/gralloc.sc8830.so". Will use given name.
2019-04-12 13:47:41.420 22410-22410/com.example.realrecyclerview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.realrecyclerview, PID: 22410
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.realrecyclerview.HarvestAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HarvestAdapter.java:48)
        at com.example.realrecyclerview.HarvestAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HarvestAdapter.java:14)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5471)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1732)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1497)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5471)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5471)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5471)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5471)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5471)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2694)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5471)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Acti

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the entry in the selector that didn't have a state associated with it. I removed the following line and it works fine on all my devices:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The runtime exception usually contains the fault in the layout or XML file. Please give out the full LogCat exception trace.

Other than that, you mentioned you want a **ColorStateList** yet you're using a drawable. Haven't used colors in a drawable selector. If all you want is plain Colous, try a color selector instead. Same XML file, just move it to "color" Res folder and exchange **android:drawable** with **android:color**

Comment: As I said in the description, doing that results in the same error. I will update the description with the full LogCat exception trace.